# script that lists anyone with more than 1 laptop in Jira Asset Management

Tags: powershell, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I am trying to write script in powershell to list all users with more than one laptop in jira asset but I don't have any idea on how to write could someone help me?

I want to find the employee upn + device name + serial number + laptops quantity

[image: here is the jira website that I want to write script to get the info from]

Comment: Find the API documentation from atlassian, then use `Invoke-WebRequest`/`Invoke-RestMethod` to query it.

Comment: do you have an example? this is the first time I am writing script for jira

Comment: an example of what? I'm not a Jira Asset Management customer, I wouldn't know where to find the docs :)

Comment: I found the api document: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/insight/intro/introduction-and-basics/

Comment: do you know now how to  find the employee upn + device name + serial number + laptops quantity